# Why is my full camera view not being rendered in cycles?

Tags: modeling, rendering, cycles-render-engine, eevee-render-engine, fspy

My camera view is set up from Fspy and after attempting to render in cycles the render window cuts off the right side. I have exported everything as an OBJ and reimported it into a new blender file and the Fspy file too, and nothing changes. Eevee renders the whole camera view just fine. so I'm thinking there's something in the cycle settings that needs to be changed.

[image]

Comment: The camera view should be the same for cycles and Eevee. If there is any bad setting I would look for it in the camera properties. Did you try creating a new camera and rendering using it? Does the problem persist or is it a problem only for the fspy imported camera? Anyway try uploading the file, I'll have a look soon

Comment: @JiříHonzák this is the file https://drive.google.com/file/d/1uvczMQOqzDOx9WOqWEN5ZU64GXR9nFbO/view?usp=share_link

Comment: The file is locked for me. You also didn't answer what you tried to fix the problem?

Comment: @JiříHonzák I'm sorry. I did use a different camera and its still happens. Ive also played around with the clip start and end values and theres still no difference. I also unlocked the file.

Comment: By the look of the picture you provided and because of the fact it works normally, you onle have your render zoomed in... Just try using mousewheel...

Comment: The picture i screenshot and uploaded is small so it could be uploaded for the question. This is a screenshot of the whole camera view in the render window and perspective camera view:

Comment: https://imgur.com/a/aVPM3bd

Comment: It is exactly as the viewport, I do not understand what your problem is? Are you talking about the stripe missing on the right? Cycles divides the render into chunks so that it can use computational resources effectively. Let the render run. After this chunk gets rendered the missing part will start to render as well

Comment: Okay, I'll give it some time and see if the chunk renders. I appreciate your help.

Comment: It definitely will. This is how cycles works

Comment: It did work thank you @JiříHonzák